# Can I apply a CSS transition to the overflow property?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to set a `transition-delay` to the `overflow` property of `body` when a `div` is clicked by adding a class to the `body` as follows:

```js
$("div").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("no_overflow");
});
```

```css
div{
  background:lime;
  height:2000px;
}
.no_overflow{  
 overflow:hidden;
}
body{  
  overflow:auto;
  transition: overflow 0 2s;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I'm div</div>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work (there's no delay). Am I doing anything wrong here?

I know this can be achieved by using **setTimeout** function, but was wondering why can't this be achieved using css transitions? Are there any specific style properties to which css transitions can be applied?

Comment: It occurred to me that, as an alternative, you could transition the `height` rather than the `overflow` property to achieve roughly the same look.

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, that can be tried. But one must take care of browser's height in order to do this. Also, that won't crop the window in the same manner when `overflow` is `hidden`.

Anyways, I ended up using `setTimeout`. ;)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are many properties that can't be transitioned. `overflow` is among them; the render engine has no idea how to transition between "hidden" and "shown", because those are binary options, not intervals. This is the same reason why you can't transition between `display: none;` and `display: block;` (for example): there are no in-between phases to use as transitions.

You can see a list of properties you can animate **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)** on Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the **only** exception to this is `visibility`, as you can only have `visible`, `hidden`, and `collapse`, meaning that there's no in-between, but it still respects animation steps; this works great for animating submenus.

Comment: @Smithee I'm not sure what you're saying the `visibility` property is the only exception to. There are multiple (n > 1) properties that you *can* transition and multiple (n > 1) that you *cannot* transition.

Answer (score 45):

You can simulate a delay with `animation`:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("body").addClass("no_overflow");
});
```

```css
div {
  background: lime;
  height: 2000px;
}

.no_overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* persist overflow value from animation */
  animation: 7s delay-overflow;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

@keyframes delay-overflow {
  from { overflow: auto; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I'm div</div>
```

You'll have to apply a separate animation to `.body` if you want a delay on removeClass, and also to take care that the two animations don't overlap or they'll cancel each other out.

Comment: Great! I was looking for a way to hide the scrollbar on a modal-container until the fade-in transition of a modal was completed. Little hacky, but this did the trick.

Comment: this is it! instead of saying "cannot be animated with a transition", show a working css only solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the only correct answer. It works!

Comment: what a magic...

Answer (score 8):

**overflow** isn't CSS animatable property. You can see full list of animatable CSS properties [there](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/).

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking at the answer, like I was, for a way to animate the cropping of an element which requires overflowing - here is the solution that worked for me: the [clip-path css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) which is animatable and very versatile.

Here is a cool tool to play around with, in order to get the proper start / end values for an animation: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/.

Answer (score 3):

Dmitry's answer should be the only accepted answer, as it is a pure CSS solution applying delay to "non-animatable" properties. However it's worth to mention, that the CSS rule applying animation should be "triggerable" each time when it is needed.

For instance, the following code does not work:

```css
@keyframes show-overflow {
  from { overflow: hidden; }
}
.hideable, .overlay {
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 50px;
}
.hideable {
  transition: height 2s;
  overflow: visible;
  animation: show-overflow 2s;  /* this line should be in separate  "triggerable" CSS rule to work */
}
.hideable.hidden {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('hideable').classList.toggle('hidden')">
  Clik HERE to hide/show the text below
</button>
<div id='hideable' class='hideable'>
  This is the text to hide and show.  
</div>
<div class='overlay'>
  This is overlaying text
</div>
```

But after moving the marked property to a separate CSS rule, everything works as expected:

```css
@keyframes show-overflow {
  from { overflow: hidden; }
}
.hideable, .overlay {
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 50px;
}
.hideable {
  transition: height 2s;
  overflow: visible;
}
.hideable:not(.hidden) {
  animation: show-overflow 2s;  /* now this works! */
}
.hideable.hidden {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('hideable').classList.toggle('hidden')">
  Clik HERE to hide/show the text below
</button>
<div id='hideable' class='hideable'>
  This is the text to hide and show.  
</div>
<div class='overlay'>
  This is overlaying text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that you can't transition between binary attributes for example `overflow: hidden;` and `overflow: visible` but it would have been really nice if instead of "transitioning" then it would be like (in js pseudo code:

```
setTimeout("applyOverflowVisible()", transitionTime);
```

But of course you can do this yourself in JavaScript but then you are splitting the code between places and it can make it difficult to understand by someone else. I guess using things like React helps but even there I would want to avoid mixing css into the js.