# CSS transition not with overflow

Tags: html, less

I have got simple div with this css attached to it

```
.users_to_c{
    height: 500px;
    width:400px;
    background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("../img/back.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 5s;
    -moz-transition: 5s;
    -ms-transition: 5s;
    -o-transition: 5s;
    transition: 5s;
    &:hover{
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

Hover part is working it shows overflow,but it works promptly.

Comment: what is the question???

Comment: @VincentRodomista more of a problem.Transition not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"overflow" is not a animatable property.

Here is a list of animatable properties:

[CSS animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Comment: Oh okay thanks!But to you know how can i animate it like facebook does?

Comment: Which feature of Facebook are you referring to?

Comment: In chats when you hover the left div it nanimates the scroller

Comment: They are not using the default scrollbars that appear when using the CSS "overflow" property. It looks like they're using a custom scrollbar that animates itself appearing/disappearing by using the "opacity" property.

Comment: Okay Thanks!I'll see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

It actually is not possible to transition the overflow property. This code works fine with qualities such as `background: red` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option to make a transition on `overflow` property.

For a more detailed answer, please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905043/1860540

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="users_to_c">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  </div>
</div>
```

and,

```
.wrap{
    height: 200px;
    width:400px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.users_to_c{ 
    width:400px;
    background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("../img/back.jpg");
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   color:red;
   padding: 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap:hover{
      overflow-y: auto;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 420px;
}
```

The idea is, create a wrapper and we will animate it by giving extra 20px padding on hover for scrollbar. So that it does not wrap inner text.

http://jsbin.com/qivukeb/edit?html,css,output

Thanks!