# Css3/Javascript transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a modal box with an animation when it appear and disappear.
I tried using css3 transition.

HTML

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
<div id="modalcontent" class="modal-content" >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close" onclick="closeList()" >x</span>
        <h2>Lista File</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <span id="sendlistButt" class="send" onclick="sendList()" >salva</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 5; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    width: 650px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 5s, opacity 5s ; /* Safari */
    transition: top 5s, opacity 5s ;
}

.animatetop {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
function close() {
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("modalcontent").classList.remove("animatetop");
}

function open() {
    document.getElementById("modalcontent").classList.add("animatetop");
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display="block";
}
```

This make the modal appear and disappear but without transition.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what's the html structure of the modal?

Comment: I've edited with html structure

Comment: Related but not an exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904886/can-i-apply-a-css-transition-to-the-overflow-property/27905043#27905043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any css transitions that run depend on the element being visible with `display:block` or similar.

By calling 
`document.getElementById("modal").style.display="none";` at the start of your `close()` function you instantly set the entire modal to be completely hidden, so the transition on the modalcontent has no effect.

Likewise in the `open()` function, the transition class is applied but the element is hidden by `display:none` so the transition does not run.

You should try to have the transition run, then after a delay set the modal to be hidden.

```
function close() {
    document.getElementById("modalcontent").classList.remove("animatetop");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("modal").style.display="none"; //hide modal after 5s delay
    }, 5000);
}
```

and for the `open`, set the modal visible first, then add the transition class:

```
function open() {
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display="block";    
    document.getElementById("modalcontent").classList.add("animatetop");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `display` property will not let browser do the animation. It works instantly. Even using `transition: display` will not help.