# CSS Keyframe animation not removing display block

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a search bar hidden by default, when you click the button it will hide or remove it depending on the state. I thought it worked great as it appeared and disappeared perfectly until i realized that i could not click on a specific element since the search div was `hidden` but actually the display was `block`. I need it to go to display `none`.

Html:

```
<div id="searchsection" class="btnlist btnlist-top blank" style="display:none">
</div>

<button id="pl-manage-search" style="background-color:#2f383f;font-size: 38px;" class="btn btn-default" type="button" title="Toggle Search" onclick="openSearch()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Css:

```
@keyframes fadinsearch {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    1% {
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fadinsearch {
    animation: fadinsearch 500ms linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadoutsearch {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.fadoutsearch {
    animation: fadoutsearch 500ms linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JS:

```
var opens = false;
function openSearch()
{
    if (opens == false)
    {
        $("div[id='searchsection']").each( function()
        {
            //$(this).toggleClass('blank fadinsearch');
            $(this).removeClass( "blank" ).addClass( "fadinsearch" );
            $(this).removeClass( "fadoutsearch" ).addClass( "fadinsearch" );
        });
        document.getElementById("searchsection").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("playlist-entries").style.paddingTop = "79px";
        opens = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $("div[id='searchsection']").each( function()
        {
            $(this).removeClass( "fadinsearch" ).addClass( "fadoutsearch" );
        });
        document.getElementById("playlist-entries").style.paddingTop = "1px";
        //document.getElementById("searchsection").style.display = "none";
        opens = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: create code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply a CSS transition to the overflow property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904886/can-i-apply-a-css-transition-to-the-overflow-property)

Comment: The answer there addresses your problem ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try animate between non numerical values.

Instead you can use `opacity` and `z-index` or `left: -100%;` or things like that because you can't change `display` to `none` with keyframes.

You can read more about it here: [Transitions and Animations in CSS- book](https://books.google.com/books?id=r5T4CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&ots=CYdVYu_D2K&dq=keyframes%20only%20values%20numerical%20css&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q=keyframes%20only%20values%20numerical%20css&f=false)