# Max-height animation with transition from value to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I played around with `CSS-transitions` and came across some strange thing, adding a transition for `max-height` from a value (e.g. `14px`) to `none`.

*There is no animation at all, the hidden elements appear and disappear immediately.*

I can see a problem, as `none` has no height, it's hard to calc the difference to animate. Changing `none` to an actual value (e.g. `120px`) works as expected.

Is there a way to get this example work, without changing the HTML structure?

```js
$("div").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("unfold");
})
```

```css
div {
    max-height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

div.unfold {
    max-height:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
First-line<br />
Second<br />
Third<br />
Fourth<br />
More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the `max-height: none` CSS-property.

I sort of managed this by using a JS solution and saving the `scrollHeight` of the element. This is the actual height of the element, without considering the `max-height` CSS-property.

```js
var INITIAL_MAX_HEIGHT = 14;

$("div").each(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var scrollHeight = $element.prop("scrollHeight");
  $element.css({"max-height": INITIAL_MAX_HEIGHT});

  $element.click(function(){
    var height = $element.height();
    if (height <= INITIAL_MAX_HEIGHT) {
      $element.animate({"max-height": scrollHeight}, 1000);
    } else {
      $element.animate({"max-height": INITIAL_MAX_HEIGHT}, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
First-line<br />
Second<br />
Third<br />
Fourth<br />
More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />More<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

by animating height if you are using jquery it has nice method called slideDown which can do good animation as below.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $('div').slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me to animate</button>
<div style="display:none">
First-line<br />
Second<br />
Third<br />
Fourth<br />
</div>
```

Comment: There is still no animation. The hidden parts just appear or disappear.

Comment: i think problem is because you are trying to animating overflow property, which can't be animated just try to make display none and height to animate updating answer give me few moment.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904886/can-i-apply-a-css-transition-to-the-overflow-property

Comment: overflow property can't be animated, so you need to animate height and display both property that is a bit complex, and jquery give handy method to animate using height slideDown check the updated answer.

Comment: Hiding the content completely is not an option, as I want the first line(s) to be visible.

Comment: then create 2 html element, 1st element will hold first line, and rest content will be in 2nd div, and animate 2nd div when 1st div is clicked like the above. :)