# css animation overflow not working on Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, overflow

I have not been able to display the last frame of this animation right. Seems like Safari cant perform an animation using overflow. Is there any other solution?

update: I dont want to have an overflow animation, but actually get that property added in the last frame.

```
@-webkit-keyframes overflow {
  0% {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
  }
  50%{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: initial;
    -moz-backface-visibility: initial;
    -webkit-overflow: initial;
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: initial;
    -moz-backface-visibility: initial;
    -webkit-overflow: initial;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.overflow-an{
  animation: 2s overflow ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation: 2s overflow ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: See if this solve you problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211261/css3-animation-not-working-in-safari

Comment: As per this overflow cannot be animated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904886/can-i-apply-a-css-transition-to-the-overflow-property/27905043

Comment: I dont want to animate the overflow, but actualy just add it in the last frame